# PDFBox : Signature fails "Can't write signature, not enough space"

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I implemented a signature feature in JAVA using PDFBox.

The signing part of my code is :

```
            ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);
            byte[] cmsSignature = new byte[0];
            
            try {
                
                Certificate[] certificationChain = SignatureUtils.getCertificateChain(alias);
                X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificationChain[0];
                PrivateKey privateKey = SignatureUtils.getSignaturePrivateKey(alias, password);
                
                CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
                ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").build(privateKey);
                gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build())
                                .build(sha1Signer, certificate));
                gen.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(Arrays.asList(certificationChain)));
                CMSProcessableInputStream msg = new CMSProcessableInputStream(externalSigning.getContent());
                CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);
                
                if (tsaUrl != null && !tsaUrl.isEmpty()) {
                    ValidationTimeStamp validation;
                    validation = new ValidationTimeStamp(tsaUrl);
                    signedData = validation.addSignedTimeStamp(signedData);
                }
                cmsSignature = signedData.getEncoded();
                
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("signature length = " + cmsSignature.length);
                    logger.debug("certificate = " + certificate.toString());
                }
                
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException | CMSException | OperatorCreationException | IOException e) {
                throw new SignatureException(e.getMessage());
            }
            
            externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);
```

Everything works fine if I use my testing auto-signed certificate I generated with the keytool command.

The problem is, when I try this code with an existing certificate which is truly certified, I get the exeption :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write signature, not enough space
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.writeExternalSignature(COSWriter.java:797)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.SigningSupport.setSignature(SigningSupport.java:48)
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work...

Any help would be appreciated ! =)

Comment: You log the "signature length". Which value does it have? And did you set the PreferredSignatureSize value?

Comment: signature length = 10721
No, I didn't set any preferred size... I didn't know there was this attribute. Maybe this is the reason why.

I will try doing this : 

   SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
   signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(0x5000);
   
   document.addSignature(signature, signatureOptions);

Comment: Ok, yes. I essentially wrote the same as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a comment you mention that you get

> signature length = 10721

in the log files and that you

> didn't set any preferred size

By default PDFBox reserves 0x2500 bytes for the signature. That's 9472 bytes decimally. Thus, just like the exception says, there's *not enough space*.

You can set the size PDFBox reserves for the signature by using a `SignatureOptions` object during `document.addSignature`:

```java
SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(20000);
document.addSignature(signature, signatureOptions);
```